# Can any one please describe me that what is oneway in aidl for android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, aidl, oneway

Can any one please describe me that what is **oneway** in **aidl** for android ?

like in below code what oneway does ?

```
oneway interface IPackageStatsObserver {

    void onGetStatsCompleted(in PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded);

}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041692/does-oneway-declaration-in-android-aidl-guarantee-that-method-will-be-called-in

Comment: Hi Rajdeep, your question is lacking detail and context. You might wanna have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question in order to get more and better answers.

Comment: Found this via google: '[The oneway keyword modifies the behavior of remote calls](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)'.

Answer (score 4):

From the Google documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

> The oneway keyword modifies the behavior of remote calls. When used, a remote call does not block; it simply sends the transaction data and immediately returns. The implementation of the interface eventually receives this as a regular call from the Binder thread pool as a normal remote call. If oneway is used with a local call, there is no impact and the call is still synchronous.